# Python script interrupts only after buffer receives data using socket and KeyboardInterrupt sent

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I'm using Python version 2.7.9 on Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit.

(Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32)

So I am writing a python IRC bot and everything works within the script.

The issue that I am having is if I send a KeyboardInterrupt, the script in the console window shows that it is still running UNTIL the bot receives data.

Situation:

> Execute script to connect to IRC server
>
> Logs onto the server no problem
>
> In console window, I send a CTRL + C
>
> Console window hangs making it seem like script is running
>
> Send bot a query message / message is sent to the channel
>
> Console shows interrupt and exit message I designated in the exception

Shouldn't the script immediately quit once a CTRL + C is sent to the console? I do have a part in the script to make it close gracefully if I send a quit message, but this part bothers me.

Here is my code where I believe it may have issues:

```
def main(NETWORK, NICK, CHAN, PORT):
   flag = True
   readbuffer = ""
   global CURRENTCHANNELS
   global MAXCHANNELS

   s.connect((NETWORK,PORT))
   s.send("NICK %s\r\n" % NICK)
   s.send("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % (IDENTD, NETWORK, REALNAME))

   while(flag):
       try:
           readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(4096)
       except KeyboardInterrupt:
           print "Interrupt received"
       finally:
            s.close()
```

Comment: Which Windows version? As [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#execution-of-python-signal-handlers) explains, when Python receives a signal, it just stashes it away to deal with after the current bytecode finishes. If that bytecode is a call to the C function `socket.recv`, that won't finish until there's data. Of course on most *nix platforms in most scenarios, the signal will interrupt the `recv`, so that isn't a problem, but you're not on *nix, you're on Windows. And that means digging into what Python's Windows code and Windows' WinSock2 code do on Ctrl-C here…

Comment: I'm using Python version 2.7.9 on Windows. I am not doing any kind of threading. The bot just sits and waits for data from a user or channel

Comment: Yes, I see "Windows", but which Windows version? (I tried to rewrite my comment to explain why that might matter.)

Comment: Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: That's which _Python_ version, not which _WIndows_ versions.

Comment: Also, does Ctrl-Break work, or does it have the same problem as Ctrl-C?

Comment: Woops sorry, Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit. Ctrl + Break has the same problem

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, with Python 2.x, Ctrl-C generally does not interrupt socket calls.

In some cases, Ctrl-Break works. If it does, and if that's good enough for you, you're done.

But if Ctrl-Break doesn't work, or if that isn't acceptable as a workaround, the only option is to set your own console ctrl-key handler, with [`SetConsoleControlHandler`](
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There's a good discussion of this [on the PyZMQ issue tracker](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/100), including a link to [some sample code](https://gist.github.com/schlamar/7921ec587dd58a72a6d6) for working around it.

The code could be simpler if you can use the `win32api` module from `PyWin32`, but assuming you can't, I think this is the code you want:

```
from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, DWORD

kernel32 = windll.LoadLibrary('kernel32')
PHANDLER_ROUTINE = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, DWORD)
SetConsoleCtrlHandler = kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler
SetConsoleCtrlHandler.argtypes = (PHANDLER_ROUTINE, BOOL)
SetConsoleCtrlHandler.restype = BOOL
CTRL_C_EVENT = 0
CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1

@PHANDLER_ROUTINE
def console_handler(ctrl_type):
    if ctrl_type in (CTRL_C_EVENT, CTRL_BREAK_EVENT):
        # do something here
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not SetConsoleCtrlHandler(console_handler, True):
        raise RuntimeError('SetConsoleCtrlHandler failed.')
```

---

The question is what to put in the `# do something here`. If there were an easy answer, Python would already be doing it. :)

According to the docs, [`HandlerRoutine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx) functions actually run on a different thread. And, IIRC, closing the socket out from under the main thread will always cause its `recv` to wake up and raise an exception. (Not the one you *want*, but still, something you can handle.)

However, I can't find documentation to prove that—it's definitely not recommended (and WinSock2 seems to officially allow the `close` to fail with `WSAEINPROGRESS`, even if no Microsoft implementation of WinSock2 actually does that…), but then you're just trying to bail out and quit here.

So, I believe just defining and installing the handler inside `main` so you can write `s.close()` as the `# do something here` will work.

---

If you want to do this in a way that's *guaranteed* to be safe and effective, even with some weird WinSock2 implementation you've never heard of being, what you need to do is a bit more complicated. You need to make the `recv` asynchronous, and use either Windows async I/O (which is very painful from Python 2.x, unless you use a heavy-duty library like Twisted), or write cross-platform `select`-based code (which isn't very Windows-y, but works—as long as your use an extra `socket` instead of the usual Unix solution of a `pipe`). Like this (untested!) example:

```
# ctypes setup code from above

def main():
    extrasock = socket.socket(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    extrasock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
    extrasock.setblocking(False)

    @PHANDLER_ROUTINE
    def console_handler(ctrl_type):
        if ctrl_type in (CTRL_C_EVENT, CTRL_BREAK_EVENT):
            killsock = socket.socket(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            killsock.sendto('DIE', extrasock.getsockname())
            killsock.close()
            return True
        return False

    if not SetConsoleCtrlHandler(console_handler, True):
        raise RuntimeError('SetConsoleCtrlHandler failed.')

    # your existing main code here, up to the try
    # except that you need s.setblocking(False) too
    try:
        r, _, _ = select.select([s, extrasock], [], [])
        if extrasock in r:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        if s in r:
            readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(4096)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # rest of your code here
```

If this makes no sense to you, the [Sockets HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) actually has a pretty good explanation of how to use `select`, and the pitfalls of using it on Windows.